# Regex matching certain character in string pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a example of many of string pattern like this but I want to show some example.

```
from:   [name:  Illianney Amada
id:     674176087]
from:   [name:  Natalia Morel-Gibbs
id:     100003799207624]
from:   [name:  Jules Kaneyge Pand
id:     100000110811550]
```

And, I would like to illustrate the parameter type like this:  (Watch **String** and **SequenceOfNumber**)

```
from:   [name:  String
id:     SequenceOfNumber]
```

but actually, it was represented from this

```
from:\t[name:\tString\nid:\tSequenceofNumber]
```

So, I would like to replace the **"\n"** that is between **"String"** and **"id:"** with **",\t"** or tab character. The result should be like this

```
from:\t[name:\tString,\tid:\tSequenceofNumber]\n
from:\t[name:\tString,\tid:\tSequenceofNumber]\n
from:\t[name:\tString,\tid:\tSequenceofNumber]\n
```

Or in other way like this

```
from:   [name:  String,    id:     SequenceOfNumber]
from:   [name:  String,    id:     SequenceOfNumber]
from:   [name:  String,    id:     SequenceOfNumber]
```

Note: I implement the regex replacing with Python module **re**

Comment: @EvertonAgner I just edit my question, sorry. It's Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
import re
fixed = re.sub(r"(\[name:.*?)\n", r"\1,\t", originalString, re.M)
```

Results in:

```
from:   [name:  Illianney Amada,       id:     674176087]
from:   [name:  Natalia Morel-Gibbs,   id:     100003799207624]
from:   [name:  Jules Kaneyge Pand,    id:     100000110811550]
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/wN7aT0

---

**Old:**

If you've only got the one `\n` there, you could do:

```
originalString = "from:\t[name:\tString\nid:\tSequenceofNumber]"
fixedString = ",\t".join(originalString.split("\n"))
```

This will split the string on `\n` and join it back together with `,\t`, resulting in:

```
from:\t[name:\tString,\tid:\tSequenceofNumber]
```

**Caveat:** in your original example, you didn't actually set a string in the variable. Are you perhaps opening this from a text file? If so, that changes the answer dramatically, because you might be looping one line at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to explain in my question. Regarding to the pattern, I have many of them. So, It would be many "\n".  :\

Comment: OK, regardless, this actually does work if you want to replace *all* of them. If you only want a handful, then you need something more complex.

Comment: Your solution is good but I would like to say sorry again. Because I did not mentioned about multiple of string pattern in single string variable. So, you solution will affect the "\n" between pattern also.

Comment: Yep absolutely -- it'll affect all of them. I see your updated post, will sort out a regex.

Comment: Updated, see new regex example.

Comment: The solution is good. But I found the problem when the given pattern is more than 8 times. it will not work after that. please take a look after line 97 in this file, please http://pastebin.com/xDuND5qQ

Comment: @Jojas Looks like that one is formatted differently than the rest? a new line is in there.

Comment: Excatly, it's different from what I asked before because I just don't want to put it too much in the question firstly. From my oberservation, I retrieve the information from Facebook Graph API and I request with different query. So, all of the result will show up incorrectly after passed 8 objects. Do you think is it problem with Facebook API or python regex?

Comment: Ok, back up -- if you're pulling this from facebook's API, you should pull it as JSON and use Python's built-in [JSON decoder/encoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

If only replace '\n' in pattern, then like this:

```
import re

data = """from:   [name:  Jules Kaneyge Pand
id:     100000110811550]
from:   [name:  abcd
id:     100000110811550]
           """

print ',\tid:'.join(re.split("[^\]]\s*\n\s*id:", data))
```

You will get:

```
from:   [name:  Jules Kaneyge Pan,  id:     100000110811550]
from:   [name:  abc,    id:     100000110811550]
```